# one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation : can't find inplace operation

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient, conv-neural-network

> I have this code below and I can't find the inplace operation that prevents the gradient from computing.

```
for epoch in range(nepoch):
    model.train()
    scheduler.step()

    for batch1 in loader1:
        torch.ones(len(batch1[0]), dtype=torch.float)
        x, label = batch1
        x = x1.to('cuda', non_blocking=True)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        pred = model(x)
        pred = pred.squeeze() if pred.ndimension() > 1 else pred
        label = (label.float()).cuda(cuda0)
        weights = torch.ones(len(label))
        loss_fun = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(weight=weights.cuda(cuda0))
        score = loss_fun(pred, label)
        label = np.array(np.round(label.cpu().detach())).astype(bool)
        pred = np.array(pred.cpu().detach()>0).astype(bool)
        torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)

        score.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

At the end I have this error that pops up:

```
Warning: Error detected in MulBackward0. Traceback of forward call        that caused the error:
File "train.py", line 98, in <module>
  pred = model(x)
File "/home/anatole2/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 550, in __call__
  result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
File "/home/anatole2/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 100, in forward
  input = module(input)
File "/home/anatole2/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 550, in __call__
  result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
File "/home/anatole2/best/PCEN_pytorch.py", line 30, in forward
  filtered[i] = filtered[i] + (1-exp(self.log_s)) * filtered[i-1]
(print_stack at /pytorch/torch/csrc/autograd/python_anomaly_mode.cpp:60)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "train.py", line 116, in <module>
  score.backward()
File "/home/anatole2/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/tensor.py", line 198, in backward
  torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
File "/home/anatole2/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 100, in backward
  allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.cuda.FloatTensor [16, 1, 80]], which is output 0 of SelectBackward, is at version 378; expected version 377 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!
```

If you could help me that'd be great !

Comment: Can you please paste the full error Traceback inside the post instead of referring to it with a link? Welcome to Stack Overflow by the way :-)

Comment: @Ronald Yeah I didn't expect it to be in the form of a link
Thx !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The in-place operation seems to be on this line:

```
File "/home/anatole2/best/PCEN_pytorch.py", line 30, in forward
  filtered[i] = filtered[i] + (1-exp(self.log_s)) * filtered[i-1]
```

Note that it is using the value from filtered[i] and then storing the result in filtered[i].  This is what in-place means; the new value overwrites the old one.

To fix it, you'd need to do something like this:

```
filtered_new = torch.zeros_like(filtered)
...
filtered_new[i] = filtered[i] + (1-exp(self.log_s)) * filtered[i-1]
```

The part that makes this a bit complicated is that this seems to be inside a loop (I assume `i` is the loop counter) and it probably uses the values from the previous pass through the loop.  The modified version is not in-place, but probably won't produce the same results as the original either.  So you may have to do something like this:

```
filtered_new[i] = filtered[i] + (1-exp(self.log_s)) * filtered_new[i-1]
```

It's impossible to solve this without seeing more code around this, but basically - look around, and replace any operation which changes existing tensors with an operation which creates new tensors to store the results of the calculation.